# grunt-express livereload configuration

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gruntjs

hello I am trying to grunt-express configuration for auto-reload feature.
but I think it has some error but I can't find it.

I'm using express-generator,node,grunt

my directory structure is following

`HRapp
 -grunt
 -bin
 -public
 -routes
 app.js`

and all static files in `public` directory

here is my `gruntfile.js` in `grunt`directory above

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    express: {
      server: {
        options: {
          port: 3000,
          bases: '../public'
        }
      }
    }
  })

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-parallel')
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch')
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-express')
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['express', 'express-keepalive'])
}
```

above code work well so I want to try livereload feature using grunt-express.
but following code doesn't work

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    express: {
      myLivereloadServer: {
        bases: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public'),
        livereload: true
      }
    }
  })

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-parallel')
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch')
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-express')
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['express', 'express-keepalive'])
}
```

all above two code is running server `localhost:3000`.
but second code seem to be cannot get any static files.

last, my package.json is here.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "express-server": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-express": "^1.4.1",
    "grunt-express-server": "^0.5.3",
    "grunt-parallel": "^0.5.1",
    "grunt-run": "^0.8.0"
  }
}
```

reference: here(https://github.com/blai/grunt-express)

any help appreciated!